# Is there a simple way to asynchronously render a report in SSRS 2008 using the webservice method?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The title says most of what I'd like to accomplish.

I'd like to render a report in SSRS 2008 using the built-in webservice methods. The report should render and the service should do some kind of call back or notification so I know the report is finished. Currently I'm rendering the reports with synchronous calls.

Is there some built-in mechanism for that? What about SSRS 2008 R2?

If not, any ideas to achieve the same result? 

I.e. I read that (at least) R2 can send the report via eMail to a given destination. This could be used as a "notification", although I'm reluctant to misuse this feature as a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating service proxy click **Advanced** button, then select the **Generate asynchronous operations** check box.

Comment: Ah. The proxy was created as WebReference. Thus no asynchronous operations were choosable. Thanks.